# How do I compare of two arrays in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

i've got an array like x, i want to do some works on it and put result in the new array  y. then i should compare this two. if they are the same by a thershold(i.e they could be a little different) that's ok and algorithm ends otherwise i should continue the iteration 
the problem is comparing these two.
they are a two 2d array with unknown elements.
i've done two different way but none of them where ok:
first way:

```
d = x - y
if d < 5 
   disp('end')
end
```

and so on
but it does not work well,honestly it doesn't work at all
the other way which i used is:

```
isequal(x,y)
```

while they are the same it will return 0 but if they are not and even with a little difference the result will be 1 and it is not ok cause as i said algorithm should consider a litlle difference and stop the iteration 
what should i do?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if d<5` in your first attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `5` is an OK threshold, then this should work:

```
d=abs(x-y);
if all(d<5)
    disp('end')
end
```

If you don't know what the threshold is, then that's a very different question. Determining a sensible threshold is dependant on your application, and is often a trade-off - there may not be a "right" answer if your data is variable. Look into some basic statistics - the `zscore` command may be a useful start.

Comment: it didn't work the answer array got numbers like 30 40 22 and so on but it accept d<5

Comment: Can you show details of the array? Code for `x` and `y`? I can't help you without any more details!

Comment: my code is too long and so complicated i dono if i put a part of it here it would be understandable,anyway the code is:  k=44;%k group
n=556;%all elements
r=12;%elements in a group
b=1;%the column number which is 1
%1st gouping data in k group.each group own a row. a is a cell array
a=grouhbandi(n,k);
e1=Ks(a,k); %the first elements of a in each row which are the k means,e1 is array
i=0;
had=1000;%limit to stop iteration
 while had>5
a=Ekmeans(a,k,r);
a=newks(a,k);%these two code calculate the new k group
e2=Ks(a,k);%this is the new Ks which will allocate in e2
had=e2-e1;
had=abs(had);
 end

Comment: If e1 and e2 are vectors, you need to use while any(had>5), otherwise if even a single element has a difference of less than 5, your loop will finish before you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

One other way to inspect the difference vector is to use "find()" function in MATLAB. As Nolan, I think you better use the absolute value of the difference.
`idx = find(abs(a-b)>threshold)` will give you the indices that exceed the threshold. If null, then you terminate your iterations.